# When i create a android app,when i click a button, how can i access this in another class?

Tags: android

Whenever I create an Android app. I  use a switch statement to access multiple  buttons. When I click a button how can  I understand which button was pressed., from another class?

The other class is not  an activity class. can anyone show me the right code.? for better understand.

My first class is...

```
 public void onClick(View v){
    switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.button1 :
                    GifView.mymethod(R.id.button1);
                final Dialog dialog1=new Dialog(context);
                dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

                Button finish1= (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.finish);
                finish1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog1.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog1.show();
                    break;
```

I want pass this button id onto another class..

```
private void init(Context context) {
    switch(?????){
        case R.id.button1:
            setFocusable(true);
            gifInputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.hen);

            gifMovie = Movie.decodeStream(gifInputStream);
            movieWidth = gifMovie.width();
            movieHeight = gifMovie.height();
            movieDuration = gifMovie.duration();
            break;
```

what can i do inside the switch statement?

```
public static int mymethod(int id) {
    int buttonId=id;
    return buttonId;
}
```

Comment: Set IDs on your buttons. In the onClick() method, fetch the ID and pass it onto the required class.

Comment: How can i pass it onto required class. Brother @ Ankur Aggarwal

Comment: Learn basic java. Methods and parameters will let your other class know what button was pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just passe an id. Like:

```
mybutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myclass.mymethod("add"); //or give your view (v)
        }
    });
```

and then some if statments.

Then in your other class, you can do:

```
void mymethod(string name){

if (name.equals("add")){
///do something here
 }
}
```

In android each view has an id so you could compare directly the id:

```
mybutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        myclass.mymethod(v.getId()); //or give your view (v)
    }
});
//on the other class
void mymethod(int name){

if (name == R.id.name_of_my_id){
///do something here
 }
}
```

Comment: What is the accepted code for anoteher class?@
user3549047

Comment: thanks everyone . this problem is solved... specially  @ user3549047. for your concept.